# iOS - [CLPlacemark timeZone]: unrecognized selector iOS 8

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, timezone, selector

I'm using this method in order to get the `timeZone` from `lat/long`.

```
-(void)getTimeZoneFromLatLong
{
    CLLocation *location = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:self.parentVC.currentCity.latitude.doubleValue longitude:self.parentVC.currentCity.longitude.doubleValue];
    CLGeocoder *geoCoder = [[CLGeocoder alloc]init];
    [geoCoder reverseGeocodeLocation: location completionHandler:^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error)
    {
        CLPlacemark *placemark = [placemarks objectAtIndex:0];
        _placemark = placemark;
    }];
}
```

Then I can use the `timeZone` in order to call :

```
EDSunriseSet *eds = [EDSunriseSet sunrisesetWithTimezone:_placemark.timeZone
           latitude:latitude.doubleValue longitude:longitude.doubleValue];
```

`EDSunriseSet` is a library in order to get `Sunrise/Sunset` values from `lat/long` and `timeZone`.

It's working perfectly, however `Crashlytics` is alerting me that `[CLPlacemark timeZone]` is incompatible with `iOS8` and lower.

How can I adapt my code for `iOS8` ?

**EDIT:**  `[_placemark timezone]` and `_placemark.timezone` are both accepted ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15417176/how-to-get-the-time-zone-name-for-a-cllocation ?

Comment: That's exactly what I'm doing

Comment: No, you didn't read correctly. That question is prior to iOS9. They are retrieving the NSTimeZone from its loc/lat witouth using `timeZone` property of `CLPlaceMark` (because it didn't existed at that time).

Comment: I can't close the question. I need answers. I used chris'solution from your link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's available from iOS 9.

```
/*
     *  timeZone
     *
     *  Discussion:
     *      Returns the time zone associated with the placemark.
     */
    @available(iOS 9.0, *)
    open var timeZone: TimeZone? { get }
```

For iOS 8, try this

```
CLLocation *currentLocaiton = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:latitude longitude:longitude];
[geoCoder reverseGeocodeLocation:currentLocaiton completionHandler:^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error) { 

if (error == nil && [placemarks count] > 0) {placeMark = [placemarks lastObject]; 
    NSRegularExpression regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"identifier = \"[a-z]*\\/[a-z]_*[a-z]*\"" options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive error:NULL]; 
    NSTextCheckingResult *newSearchString = [regex firstMatchInString:[placeMark description] options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [placeMark.description length])]; 
    NSString *substr = [placeMark.description substringWithRange:newSearchString.range]; NSLog(@"timezone %@",substr); 
}
```

Comment: Yeah my question means how can I achieve what I'm doing but for iOS 8.

Comment: You want to set timeZone for IOS 8 also?

Comment: I want to get timeZone from lat/long for iOS 8 yes. My code is working for iOS 9 and higher.

Comment: There are two ways to do that in iOS 8.
<br>1st is
<br>[Find a library here] https://github.com/Alterplay/APTimeZones and 

    CLLocation *location = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:100.12345
                                                      longitude:80.12345];
    
    NSTimeZone *timeZone = [[APTimeZones sharedInstance] timeZoneWithLocation:location];
    NSLog(@"%@", timeZone);

Comment: 2nd is
    CLLocation *currentLocaiton = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:latitude longitude:longitude];
    
    [geoCoder reverseGeocodeLocation:currentLocaiton completionHandler:^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error) {

Comment: if (error == nil && [placemarks count] > 0) {placeMark = [placemarks lastObject];
         NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"identifier = \"[a-z]*\\/[a-z]*_*[a-z]*\"" options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive error:NULL];
            NSTextCheckingResult *newSearchString = [regex firstMatchInString:[placeMark description] options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [placeMark.description length])];
            NSString *substr = [placeMark.description substringWithRange:newSearchString.range];
            NSLog(@"timezone  %@",substr); 
    
        }

Comment: write an answer if you want to have the accepted answer.

Comment: Are facing any other problem? I hope this should work for you. if not then reply here, I'll help to find another solution, that can solve your problem.

Comment: I used the second solution you provided. it's working.

Comment: OK.. Updated actual answer