# Get time from GPS in xcode for a ios device

Tags: ios, iphone, cllocation

I'm looking for a functionality to get the actual time of the iphone from the location. I already tried with `timestamp` from `CLLocation`. But it returning the device time only. How to get that exact time.

Note: We can get timestamp from lat and long using some apis.

Comment: Do you want to get the time that the location was created (which is the `timestamp` property), or the current time of a device given a specific location?

Comment: i need the time based on device location, not timestamp. Even the time zone has been changed.

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9188871/how-to-identify-timezone-from-longitude-and-latitude-in-ios/27054583) goes over how to get the timezone from a location. Is that a step in the right direction?

Comment: You can see this solve. I thinks it's can help you.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31920829/getting-time-from-gps-on-ios