# Getting time from GPS on iOS

Tags: ios, gps, core-location

I am working on a tracer app. The app requires to know the device location with high accuracy, i.e. it uses location services and ignores locations with horizontal accuracy worse than 20 meters. `CLLocation` does not declare explicitely if it was determined via GPS or not. However, if the horizontal accuracy is 20 meters or better, it can be supposed that it is a location from GPS.

Additionally, I need to know the timestamp when the location was determined. I know about the property `timestamp` in class `CLLocation`. However, I would like to get the timestamp from GPS, not the system time.

Is it possible to get the GPS time? I don't care about cases when the GPS signal is not available. I just need to get the GPS time for a GPS location (location with high accuracy) I have just received.

In other questions on stackoverflow, the following code snippet is suggested:

```
CLLocation* location = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:(CLLocationDegrees) 0.0 longitude:(CLLocationDegrees) 0.0];
NSDate* now = location.timestamp;
```

Is there any guarantee that `location.timestamp` is something more GPS-related than `[NSDate date]`?

It seems not to be true if the automatic time setting is turned off. If I go to Settings -> General -> Date & Time and turn off "Set Automatically", the property `timestamp` contains the manually set system time. So is it more-GPS related at least when automatic time setting is turned on?

Comment: By "GPS time" I assume you mean the time that the single was sent from the satellite? If so, that will be different from each satellite. GPS works by looking at the time difference between the system time and the timestamps of the signals it receives. The time on CLLocation is what you're after more than likely. TBH, I'm not really sure what you mean by "GPS Time".

Comment: By "GPS time", I mean the time that was sent by satellite. However, if I set manually the system time on the device, than `timestamp` contains that manually set time. So I guess that `timestamp` on `CLLocation` is just the system time of the device and has no relation to the time sent by GPS satellite. I just wonder if this is really true and if it is true even if the system time is set to be synchronized automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the timestamp is calculated device-side and is most likely not related to the satellite's timestamp.
CoreLocation is totally opaque in it's work and it sounds very unlikely from Apple to let you access raw data like GPS satellites timestamps...

Comment: To support the statement in this answer that Apple does not provide GPS timestamps, see Apple's response here: https://forums.developer.apple.com/message/205233#205233

Comment: Broken link ...

Comment: @BillF https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/70620

Answer (score 2):

```
However, I would like to get the timestamp from GPS, not the system time.
```

You cannot get the timestamp that the GPS chip provides.

If the user artificially sets a wrong time, ios uses this offset in its locations, too.

```
I just need to get the GPS time for a GPS location (location with high accuracy) I have just received.
```

If the device is set to auto setting the system time, the gps location time should be acurate.

```
So is it more-GPS related at least when automatic time setting is turned on?
```

Yes

```
Is there any guarantee that location.timestamp is something more GPS-related than [NSDate date]?
```

Its always more related, [NSDate date] is the current system time, while location.time is the time related to the location recording time. This can be offset by e.g 0.6s, or even much more for the first fix after start.

To check whether the location is current or not, Apple recomends to calcuilate the difference between system time and location time.

Comment: OK, that is a good point. `location.timestamp` is better than `[NSDate date]` as it eliminates the delay between the recording time and the time the location is processed by the app. However, the question is: Is `location.timestamp` always just the system time or is it the time sent by the GPS satellite?

Comment: It is some kind of syncronized system time with gps time.. Apple seems to store the offset that the user sets, and keeps this offset syncromized (e.g when changingtimezone) . I am not sure what they exactly do, but this is how I perceived it.

Comment: Can you suggest any experiment, observation, statement in a document or some other kind of argument to prove that `location.timestamp` is not just a pure system time please?

Comment: Of course such document does not exist, because apple hides all internal details, But obsrvation: yes, look at the milliseconds part, GPS modules use nearly always 0, so they have no fraction after the second. While system time usually has  never the millisecond at 0. (the chance  is 1:1000)

Comment: I have tried to log `location.timestamp` and the millisecond part is not zero. Of course, this can be a matter of OS version, I have observed this on iPhone 5 with iOS 8.4.1.